# How to install Rviz with Kinetic distro?

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to add Rviz to ROS Kinetic 1.12.12, but there isn't instructions for this version on the [user's guide](https://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide).

I tried to run `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rviz` but the console says it's "Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-rviz".

Is there something i'm missing ?

Thank you for your replies, have a good day.

---

(edit)

I forgot to mention i am using a Raspberry Pi3 with Raspbian stretch, that might not help...
So I ran the sudo apt update and i had the same errors as in #q325039. I followed the steps, now everything is normal I have the following output :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
Hit:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu stretch InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

But i am still unable to locate the ros-kinetic-rviz package :(

And `uname -a` gives me :

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I didn't installed ROS myself, i flashed an image i found [here](https://neverbenever.wordpress.com/2017/12/20/install-ros-and-opencv-in-raspberry-piraspbian-stretch/) on my SD card because i could not build all the libraries on my Pi (not enough RAM...). It looks like it has been installed from sources on the website, so i would like to try to build rviz from sources but have no idea how to do that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327891/how-to-install-rviz-with-kinetic-distro-?/) by [goowza](https://answers.ros.org/users/43624/goowza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-08**:
Please post the output of `sudo apt update` and check whether you're running into #q325039.

Also: please show us the output of `uname -a`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-09**:\

> Okay i forgot to mention i am using a Raspberry Pi3 with Raspbian stretch

yes, that is important information to share. And also why I asked for the output of `uname -a`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-09**:
How did you install ROS? Using `apt` or building everything from source?

If the latter: you cannot mix `apt` with from-source builds.

Additionally: I'm not entirely sure, but I don't know whether there are binary packages available of ROS Kinetic for RPi's with Raspbian (Stretch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, I realized the [ROSberry page](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi) provided a link to download an SD Card Image with Ubuntu 16.04 (LXDE) and ROS Kinetic installed.
Rviz is already installed on this image and runs normally, so my problem is fixed ! I wish i saw that earlier haha :v

Thank you for your answers !

---

Originally posted by [goowza](https://answers.ros.org/users/43624/goowza/) with karma: 16 on 2019-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0